# symfony 1.4 propel combine two AND in scopes with OR in where clause

Tags: symfony-1.4, propel

I am re-coding website on Symfony 1.4 with propel and from an hour and more I am searching how I can do this with Propel ? ( Propel 1.4 on Symfony 1.4)

```
SELECT * FROM 'test' WHERE ( var_1 = 1 AND var_2 = 2) OR ( var_1 = 2 AND var_2 = 1)
```

I am trying with this code

```
$c = new Criteria();
$c->add(MessagesPeer::USER_FROM, $user->getId(), Criteria::EQUAL);
$c->addAnd(MessagesPeer::USER_TO, $this->user_id, Criteria::EQUAL);
$c->addOr(MessagesPeer::USER_FROM, $this->user_id, Criteria::EQUAL);
$c->add(MessagesPeer::USER_TO, $user->getId(), Criteria::EQUAL);
```

but the results is this:

```
WHERE (messages.USER_FROM=16405 OR messages.USER_FROM=56) AND messages.USER_TO=16405
```

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

Your Propel version is way out of date. I would highly recommend that you upgrade your Propel to at least 1.5, which was release more than  [6 years ago](http://propelorm.org/blog/2010/04/26/propel-1-5-stable-released.html).

Using v1.5+, you would use the new Query class, like this:

```
$messages = MessagesQuery::create()
    ->condition('cond1', 'Messages.UserFrom = ?', $user->getId())
    ->condition('cond2', 'Messages.UserTo = ?', $this->user_id)
    ->combine(['cond1', 'cond2'], 'and', 'cond12')
    ->condition('cond3', 'Messages.UserFrom = ?', $this->user_id)
    ->condition('cond4', 'Messages.UserTo = ?', $user->getId())
    ->combine(['cond3', 'cond4'], 'and', 'cond34')
    ->where(['cond12', 'cond34'], 'or')
    ->find();
```

See the Propel [Relational API documentation](http://propelorm.org/Propel/reference/model-criteria.html#relational-api) for using conditions.